# Can a novel and potentially important observation be published without the scaffolding of an entire theory or experiment?

Tags: publishability

I have what I feel is a novel and potentially helpful observation in the field of neuroscience, which connects it to another field, but it is just that - an observation. If this needs to become publishable, do I need to develop an entire theory around it (which is difficult, given that neuroscience isn't dealing with the relatively "simpler" objects that we see in physics or mathematics). The other alternative is to gather as much evidence from prior studies as possible that point to the observation being valid.

How does someone who is theoretically inclined go about this?

Comment: How much training do you have in neuroscience?

Comment: None, to be honest. I've been learning from the iBiology website and following up by reading the reference papers mentioned.

Comment: Related: [Publishing a novel idea without experiments and results](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143807/), [Can a psychology article be published without verifiable results?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/110508/)

Comment: Just to be clear, the observation is really from a computational perspective, not pure neurobiology.

Comment: @AppliedAcademic: Points taken, and edits made accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Your observation will need to be novel and interesting. From your description, it might also need some preliminary calculations to back it up.

The original paper describing the [flyby anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyby_anomaly) is an example.

Comment: Just curious, would arXiv be a good place for this? I'd ideally like to elucidate the basics of the idea and continue working on it and add evidence/justification as I make progress.

Comment: @Joebevo I'm not familiar with neuroscience, but I'd guess no, because it doesn't look like the arXiv has much neuroscience.